# Selector no funciona

Tags: php, javascript, html, modal

Buenas tardes, tengo una tabla en la que tengo un checkbox de selector de registros. Quiero seleccionar unos registros para cambiar el valor de una variable común a todos ellos pero no tengo forma de pasar esos valores por POST. Todo pasa por un modal pero no me importaría saltarme el modal y que funcionase directo

```
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <table data-toggle="table" width="auto"  data-show-refresh="true" data-show-toggle="true" data-show-columns="true" data-search="true" data-select-item-name="toolbar1" data-pagination="true" data-sort-name="date" data-sort-order="desc">
                <div class="pull-right">
                            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                            <li class="">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add lesson</button>
                            </li>
                            <li class="">
                                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#teacher_payments" id="delete" class="btn btn-info" name="">Paid selected lessons</a>
                            </li>    
                            <li class="">
                                <a href="teachers.php" class="btn btn-danger">Back</a>    
                            </li>    
                            </ul>
                </div>
                <br><br><br>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Lesson</th>
                        <!--<th>Teacher</th>-->
                            <th>Student</th>
                            <th align="center">Date</th>
                            <th align="left">Start</th>
                            <th data-field="state" data-checkbox="true"></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php $query = mysql_query("select * from teacher_class
                            LEFT JOIN class ON class.class_id = teacher_class.class_id
                            LEFT JOIN subject ON subject.subject_id = teacher_class.subject_id
                            LEFT JOIN student ON student.student_id = teacher_class.student_id
                            where teacher_id = '$get_id' order by date DESC")or die(mysql_error());


                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                                    $id = $row['teacher_class_id'];
                    ?>
                        <tr>                                    
                            <td valign="middle"><?php echo $row['class_name']; ?></td>
                        <!--<td><?php //echo $row['teacher_id']; ?></td>-->
                            <td><?php echo "<a data-toggle=\"modal\" href='exams.php?id=$student_id'>$name $lastn</a>";?></td>
                            <td><?php echo date("d/m/Y",strtotime($row['date'])); ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <input id="optionsCheckbox" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                            </td>
                        <?php } ?>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                </form>

    <!-- /.modal -->

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="teacher_payments" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header" style="background-color:#333">
                <form name="form2" role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 id="myModalLabel">Add Lesson</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="background-color:#111">
                <input class="form-control" name="firstname"  id="proposalId1" type="text" placeholder = "Firstname">
                    <label>Lastname:</label>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer" style="background-color:#111">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button name="switch" class="btn btn-primary">Yes</button>
                </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
    <!-- /.modal -->


<?php
if (isset($_POST['switch'])){
$id=$_POST['selector'];
$N = count($id);
for($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{

    $result = mysql_query("update teacher_class set paymentstatus = 'Paid' where teacher_class_id = '$id[$i]'");
}
?>
<script>
    window.location = "teacher_class_control.php?id=<?php echo $get_id; ?>";
</script>
<?php }  ?>
```

Comment: Alguna idea por favor??

Comment: ¿Podrías ser conciso y explícito? No se entiende qué quieres hacer.

Comment: No entiendo bien tu pregunta,

Comment: El tema es que tengo una tabla, en cada registro <td></td> tengo un selector de registro con un checkbox... hasta ahí bien. lo que quiero es que al seleccionar varios registros (varios checkboxes) le de al boton "Paid selected lessons" y que cambie en todos ellos el valor de un campo, es decir, como si los borrase pero en vez de borrarlos hacer un update de cada uno de ellos por POST

Comment: Le doy al botón pero no llegan los $id al isset porque lo he comprobado poniendo un echo. Me sale 0. Yo creo que se pierden en el modal

Comment: En la ventana modal tienes un formulario independiente, es por eso que no te llegan los campos de la tabla.

Comment: se lo he quitado y sigue igual

Comment: Actualiza el código en la pregunta, para tratar de ver lo que está pasando. y agrega un **var_dump($_POST);** para ver lo que estás recibiendo al procesar el formulario.

Comment: array(1) string(0)

Comment: vale he visto que tengo un form dentro del modal... lo he quitado pero ahora cuando le doy a Yes en el modal no hace nada...